# What are these seed pods?

Tags: identification, seeds

I found these seed pods in some flower pots that I picked up roadside for free. I've been scouring the internet but can't find anything that looks like them. Does anybody know what they might be? Any help appreciated! [image]

[image]

Comment: Might help to know where you are located. :)

Comment: Northern Illinois. I'm not sure if they were from plants that were in the pots, or if a squirrel stashed them there. I haven't opened them up b/c I was thinking of planting them and wasn't sure if that would destroy their viability? If not then I'll crack one open and snap a pic.

Comment: Okay... I think maybe it's some kind of immature walnut? The hard/leathery skin peeled off and what was left looked kind of like a fig. The pic above is what it looked like once I opened it up. It was hard to get a good shot but the inside structure was very similar to a walnut with a tiny forming nut/seed in the middle. So that's my best guess, though I've never seen any that small before. Thoughts?

Comment: What is the scale?  I found pics of walnut (Quercus nigra) and though they are similar especially the one you broke open I just don't think it is walnut.  Did you find these in Illinois?  I mean along the roadside in Illinois?  Really need some scale, though.  The skin of yours is smooth where the walnut seeds are very ridged.  What types of trees are indigenous and are found in the native brush?

Comment: https://www.bing.com/cr?IG=1FFE0F1E92474E648ECB6438F116FB63&CID=35488490F63165772F988E45F76E64C9&rd=1&h=Q0_AyHasnwHDaHSCM3fjv3CJlApI_Tjzg0SUvW7uCd4&v=1&r=https%3a%2f%2ffarm2.staticflickr.com%2f1438%2f5178000508_e2efdcda64_z.jpg&p=DevEx,5218.1

Comment: Where did my earlier comment run off to?  Oh well.  I just realized you gave a great picture for scale!  And this was a roadside fruit/plant stand?  My first inclination was mummified pomegranite.  Like a dried up mummified head?  So small though!  Was there any sign of seed when you opened this up?http://www.bing.com/cr?IG=20997C75EF734CF3BD98EC6DB3BA0911&CID=15EDA020ECFE69D2008BAAF5EDA16870&rd=1&h=J56FlgkcOCoG4nbQglbPEpesmgOvZ3hcz2b08XKnmoA&v=1&r=http%3a%2f%2fpomegranates.org%2fphotos%2f3%2ffotolia_19716263_x.jpg&p=DevEx,5272.1

Comment: I am OCD with ID...good grief.  Okay how about white walnut/butternut?  Juglans cinerea?http://www.agritech.tnau.ac.in/forestry/forestry_tree_seeds/index2.html#

Comment: stormy - yes, I think you're on to something there (white walnut). I was also thinking could be black walnut, either one. There are plenty of these trees around the area where I live so it would make sense!

Comment: They look a lot like what we call black walnut here near Toronto, if Colin's ID doesn't turn out to be correct.

Comment: Could easily be one of the several varieties of Hickory nut. Walnut's a good shot too, but they look a bit small for that.

Answer (score 2):

This could well be the native American Bitternut Hickory (*[Carya cordiformis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carya_cordiformis)*) or the Shagbark Hickory (*[Carya ovata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carya_ovata)*). The former with smooth bark is more common than the latter with rough peeling bark.

Squirrels and chipmunks like to collect these nuts for their winter stores and will very readily create holes in the soil of your potted plants to bury them.  As a result it is quite common to see a hickory tree appear in among your geranium collection.

Edit:
[image: Bitternut nuts from this year's crop]
and again
[image: More stuff]